# How to stop/cancel alarm manager in another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-service, alarmmanager

I am creating alarm in **Activity A** & stopping/cancelling in another **Activity B**. I tried hard but no luck, below is my code :

**MainAcitivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 12 * 60 * 60, pendingIntent); 

    } //end onCreate

}
```

**MyReceiver**

```
    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {

        @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
           Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
           context.startService(service1);

         }

    }
```

**MyAlarmService**

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service 

{
     private NotificationManager mManager;

     @Override
     public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
     {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
     }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
       super.onCreate();
    }

   @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
   @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
   {
       super.onStart(intent, startId);

       mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

       Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());

       intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

       PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
       notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!", pendingNotificationIntent);

       mManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

**NextActivity**

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           Intent intentt = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
           PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 10, intentt, 0);
           AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
           stopService(intentt);
           alarm.cancel(pintent);
    }   
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.NextActivity"
            android:label="Next Screen">
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MyAlarmService"
                 android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

It is still firing alarm, unable to stop/cancel after doing this.

Answer (score 1):

When creating your alarm, you use this `PendingIntent`:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.getAppContext(), MyReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 10, myIntent,0);
```

When you try to cancel it, you are using this `PendingIntent`:

```
Intent intentt = new Intent(MainActivity.getAppContext(), NextActivity.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 10, intentt, 0);
```

You need to use the same code to create the `PendingIntent` when you want to cancel the alarm. Use `getBroadcast()` instead of `getService()` and use `MyReceiver.class` instead of `NextActivity.class`.

Also, you don't need to save the application context in `MainActivity`. You can remove all this static stuff. You can just use `this` as the `Context` parameter when doing `new Intent(Context, Thing.class)`

Comment: Thanks for reply, let me have a try

Comment: I tried as per your answer, but no luck still facing same issue

Comment: All looks fine. Please uninstall and reinstall your app.

Comment: Also, your call to `stopService()` won't work now, since you've changed `intentt` to contain a broadcast `Intent`. You will need to create another (different) `Intent` to pass to `stopService()` stop your service. You can also call `pintent.cancel()` to cancel the `PendingIntent` after you call `alarm.cancel()`, but this shouildn't be necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75371/discussion-between-vvb-and-david-wasser).

Comment: makes no sense. sorry
explain please xactly what is hapenning
Also, you've set this alarm so that it repeats every 12 * 60 * 60 milliseconds, that's every 43 seconds
How do you know that the cancel isnt working?
you can also check the pending alarms list using "adb shell dumpsys alarm"

Comment: You mean within short span of time Android OS fires number of alarms & those are getting fired in next few times though cancel call works. So simply I need to wait for something 30 minutes to check whether it is cancelled or not., am I right?

Comment: I don't know exactly. You could change the repeating interval so that you are sure that your alarm is being canceled. You should add logging to your `onReceive()` so you can determine when it is being called. You can check with `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to see if your alarm is still pending. You need to dig a bit more to see what is happening. How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: @David Wasser  I have a similar use case here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61161676/android-cancel-alarm-and-pendingintent-in-different-activity  I would appreciate any insights you could offer on how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling methods as static  way from which is not running for doing task use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) which is used for communicate between two component with in same process.

See following example :[Android Program to Demonstrate Local BroadCastManager](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-demonstrate-local-broadcast-manager/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but can you please figure out problem in my code?

Comment: @VB: calling methods from one activity to another is also big problem so change current code with `LocalBroadCastManager` then i'm sure problem will solve

Comment: @VVB: let me know if you have any issue in implementing `LocalBroadCastManager`

Comment: Ok fine. Will implement it first & let you know if face any issues.

Comment: @VVB: In provided example link `Activityone` means `MainActivity` and `MainActivity` means `NextActivity` in your code

Comment: Please see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113103/can-i-use-alarmmanager-with-localbroadcastmanager-on-android

Comment: @VVB:  CommonsWare Sir answer if for different case. you can cancel/ stop `alarm` using  `LocalBroadCastManager`

Comment: Ok let me try with last comment

Comment: @VVB: just declare `AlarmManager alarmManager` outside `onCreate` method in MainActivity  and call `alarmManager.cancel()` from `onReceive`  to cancel Alarm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75370/discussion-between-vvb-and--k).

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542099/cant-stop-the-ringing-alarm-from-another-activity#51542099 @ρяσѕρєяK

Answer (score -1):

OnButton Click Write below code , its working for me!!!!

```
            finish();


            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),

                    MyBroadcastReceiver.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent
                    = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),
                    alaramid, myIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager
                    = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

//Navigate to your Activity
            Intent ii = new Intent(DisplayReminder.this, MenuActivity.class);
            ii.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(ii);

            finish();
```